# How to authenticate AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax

I have designed a website which uses AJAX. I have a PHP page named store.php which accepts data sent by POST method and stores in the database.

How do I implement authentication into store.php? I only want a user logged into my site to use store.php.

Currently I am using htaccess to redirect the requests for store.php but I don't think that is a good solution.

Comment: What are you currently using for authentication in your web site?

Comment: Username/password based authentication. If there is a valid match I use $_SESSION to store some value which is checked to see if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: the session gets sent in the Ajax request as well, so the basic rule is, if you allow the Ajax request to do what you would allow a normal (web page) request to do, you're pretty much on the safe side.

Comment: Oh.. why did I not think that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any AJAX Call to a Server Script will still include the session id in the request.  If you are implementing sessions in your site, then start the session and you will be able to see session variables for the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Store a token associated with the user in your database. Make sure that the token will be unique and not guessable. Also store the same token in a hidden form field so that it gets posted back to the page. Ensure on the server that the token is present in the posted form values and check that it is valid.

Comment: Just noting that the accepted answer by Jeff Lambert is correct. The suggestion given in my answer here is technically correct but it's better not to implement your own security if possible. Just use the default session security.

Answer (score 0):

The security of Ajax requests is not a simple matter. They can be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks and replay attacks, to name a few. I'd recommend reading this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Ajax-Security-Billy-Hoffman/dp/0321491939](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321491939). It will give you lots of good information on the subject.

As for your question, specifically: once your PHP session has been set up, those session cookies will apply to Ajax requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a persistent state for the user.  The best way to implement this in PHP is to utilize sessions.

There is great documentation on it:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

I normally just include the exact same code I use to authenticate on the rest of my site in the ajax-called page. I use `SESSION` to hold a sessionID, and the rest is handled in my DB. I usually end up just adding a line like this..

```
require_once('loginProcedures.php'); 
//Login Authentication takes place here using SESSION ID

if (!$me['validLogin']) die("Invalid Authentication");

//perform actions and echo your result for a valid login.
```