# ajax php security issue

Tags: php, ajax, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to authenticate AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783130/how-to-authenticate-ajax-call)

I have a page `ajax_check_user_pass` that checks user's username and password through ajax.

Ajax code in this page posts username and password to a php file `php_check.php`.
The `php_check.php` checks username and password to match in a database.

How can I be sure that username and password that php_check.php recieves is from `ajax_check_user_pass` and is not faked by someone?

I have used sessions but it's not working. Also, I know that checking referrer is not a reliable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it really matter? If you're worried about bruteforcing, implement an auto-blocking mechanism after x attempts.

Comment: It is user input; how could it be faked? What attack are you trying to defend against?

Answer (score 4):

The fact is, you don't know who is sending you username's and password's, the fact that they have to enter this information is proof that you don't know who they are, as long as you sanitize the posted information, it should work exactly how you want it to.

Many sites implement a maximum number of attempts, but really that's up to you.

Comment: his question was not "who" but how to verify the origin of the request.

Comment: "who" *IS* the origin, the identity of the requester.

Comment: > "How can I be sure that username and password that php_check.php recieves is from ajax_check_user_pass"

Comment: my question is how to prevent someone to post some guessed usernames and passwords to find a correct one. I think auto blocking machanism based on IP is not a secure one.

Comment: My point is that it is a public facing form, someone can just type guesses into it anyways...

Answer (score 0):

This kind of attacks are called [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF) and they can be avoided by passing a challenge token stored in the session or a cookie with every request a form or ajax call makes on your site and checking it to be valid before doing any further operation.

Read this:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Also make sure to regenerate this token every X minutes or Y pageviews, whatever comes first.

Comment: It is my opinion that CSRF protection on a public facing login form seems a bit pointless...