# In hybrid app, how to confirm that only your app is accessing the server-side pages

Tags: php, cordova, security, hybrid-mobile-app

Hybrid apps are obviously a bit new, so it's hard to find good information on this. I know that I need to allow cross origin resource sharing on my server side pages, but this clearly adds a security flaw. On a phonegap/cordova app, I only have client-side control with ajax calls to my server-side page. This means that anyone can access my php pages. This means that anyone can essentially mimic my app by accessing all my data like account info, etc.  My question is how can I confirm that only my app is accessing these pages? Please provide specific coding examples.

Comment: If there is private information on your server, you would like to authenticate a user before hes accessing it. I personally would send a token from server side and store it in the app once user authenticates himself. No auth - no token, no token - no access to private information. What about ajax and php... if you have login/auth system, you should check is user logged in/authenticated on server side in php and only then send response to client side back to the js.

Comment: Also chech [Ajax php security](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5783130/5925366)

Comment: Of course all of the security/checking is done server-side. I just know that it is clearly a security flaw when you have CORS enabled without checking who is accessing the pages. Then anyone can essentially replicate my app by looking at my client-side code and copying my ajax calls to php pages. Of course they can't do anything "harmful" if all checks are server-side. I just want to make sure that only my app can ever access these pages. I am also already using JSON web tokens to authenticate login. I just don't want other people to have access to the php pages at all.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/848788/5925366)

Comment: Have you tried someting like this : https://github.com/dcaunt/google-play-license-verifier ?
You can use it with https://github.com/mobilino/Phonegap-android-license-plugin
The second one is a cordova plugin that will get the licence key from google play for your app. The first one is the server side key validator. I am trying to find a similar solution for Ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered your question, and many others like it, in this blog post: [Client authenticity is not the server's problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem).

> One of the most basic rules of application security is **input validation**. The reason this rule is so fundamental is because your server only has control (and visibility) over the software running on itself. Every other device on the Internet is a black box that you can communicate with over networking protocols. You can't see what it's doing, you only see the messages that it sends.

...

> The server should remain agnostic to the client.
>
> The software on the client and the software on the server should have a mutual distrust towards each other. Any messages that the server receives should be validated for correctness and handled with care. Data should never be mixed with code if you can help it.

...

> The take-away is: Instead of trying to control your users, focus on making their misbehavior inconsequential to the stability and integrity of your server.

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked here every day.

What you want to do is logically impossible. There is no solution. You cannot control the client.

Comment: So you're saying that all hybrid apps are vulnerable to this security flaw? Seems a bit odd as they are starting to become increasingly popular.

Comment: No, what we're saying is that this isn't a real problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: How is it not a problem? While it is not necessarily a security flaw if the all the checks are done server-side, someone could easily replicate your app by checking the client-side code and replicating the ajax calls.

Comment: @lazyboy78 no, I am saying you can't control the client that connects to your server. Any client.  Any server. Everywhere. Always.

Comment: Of course. Every halfway decent programmer knows that. I was just wondering if there was a clever work around solution to offer some type of pseudo security for it. I guess not. But like I said before, anyone can essentially mimic any app like Snapchat by just copying the ajax requests. This is not necessarily a security flaw, but it is a bit annoying. I presume the best thing to do would be to contantly monitor your server