# Allow only PHP request from Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, security, crud

I have some PHP pages that receive POST requests and make CRUD operations in my MySQL database...

I would like to know if there is a way to allow only my Android application to do those requests in my pages...

As my application requires Google Login (which Google IDs are already registered in my database), I was thinking in check if client's Google ID exists on database via PHP script, but it could be faked, right?

Is there any other way to allow only my Android App to make CRUD in my database? Maybe using another language beside PHP

Thanks in advance

Comment: use some `auth tokens` to verify the user

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815261/in-hybrid-app-how-to-confirm-that-only-your-app-is-accessing-the-server-side-pa and many, many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a way to allow only my Android application to do those requests in my pages...

This is an [impossible request](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem).

You cannot guarantee that end users are using your application to send data to your server over a public network (i.e. the Internet). Full stop, not gonna happen.

What you should do *instead* is ensure your server-side code is written to where, regardless of what data is hurled at it, your server doesn't get hacked.

Comment: But google API can prevent from other apps access

Answer (score 0):

I would store a secret key in your app and send that along with the request to log the user in. This secret key would be stored on the server and compared at login. If the key matches and user is authenticated then log user in.

Comment: The secret key also should be stored on the client-side, so anyone can easy to get the secret key too.